# How to add Slide numbering to PowerPoint presentation

Tags: powerpoint

I'd like to know how I can add the slide numbering (current page/total pages) to my Powerpoint presentation, please. Any idea how that can be accomplished?

Thank you.

Comment: right click on slides pane and then click "add slide". then you can drag it around too and put it where you want.

Comment: actually for your information this forum is for programming only though not for this type of question. I didn't downvote you but for your information thats why you are being downvoted.

Comment: i ask how can i add automatically total pages in 100 diapositives, in each diapo i have to add numberofpage/total pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow instructions here that are indicated in this link to add the number of pages / total number: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/show-the-slide-number-and-total-number-of-slides-on-every-slide-HA010242545.aspx

> 1. On the View tab, in the Presentation Views group, click Slide Master,
>      and then click the slide master thumbnail.
> 2. On the Insert tab, in the Text group, click Text Box, and then drag to
>      draw the text box where you want the slide number to appear on your
>      slides.
> 3. With the cursor still in the text box, on the Insert tab, in
>      the Text group, click Slide Number.
> 4. In the text box, place your cursor
>      before the <#>, and then type '**Slide**'.
> 5. Place your cursor after the <#>,
>      and then type '**of x**' , where x equals the total number of slides in your
>      presentation.

Comment: place your cursor before the <#>,  but i don't have <#> i have just ‹N°›

Comment: dont do that part then. Instead Step 4 for you will be  this:after Step 3, your Step 4 is to type "/" after the number template placeholder, and then step 5 will be simply type the number "100" for you. Your master slide will now be <Current Slide> / 100 and it should say the <correct #> / 100 on every slide now.

Comment: The ‹N°› instead of the <#> is most likely because you're using a French or other language version of PowerPoint rather than English.  The same suggestion is good:  Make it  "‹N°› / 100"  You'll have to supply the correct number of slides in the presentation yourself; PPT has no feature for this.

Answer (score 0):

On the Insert Menu, click "Slide Number"

Comment: yes i know but how can i get number of pages, total of pages , i have to add number of page / total pages in my ppt which contain 100 pages!!